# bash shell issue with echo call from custom function

Tags: bash

I'm in the process (v.painful) of learning the bash language and I'm fighting with the code below.  Any explanation for it's current behaviour would be greatly appreciated.

### code

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function useless
{
    echo "$1"
    return 0
}

function call-and-report
{
    TEST_CRITERIA="$1"
    
    if $TEST_CRITERIA
    then
        echo "passed"
    else
        echo "failed"
    fi
}

call-and-report $(useless  "Hello World")
```

### issue

I'm expecting the following console output:

```
Hello World
passed
```

Instead I'm seeing the following output:

```
./../test.sh: line 13: Hello: command not found
failed
```

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing up function return values and output. Barmar's answer should cover it, but just to make sure: `$1` in `call-and-report` is a string (the output from `useless`) and not anything indicating if `useless` has been successful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(command)` executes `command` and then substitutes its standard output into the command line. So whatever `useless` prints is not printed on the terminal, it's substituted back into the calling command line.

So your last command becomes:

```
call-and-report Hello World
```

Then inside `call-and-report`, `$1` is `Hello`, and you assign that to `TEST_CRITERIA`. When you do

```
if $TEST_CRITERIA
```

is equivalent to

```
if Hello
```

This tries to execute `Hello` as a command. Since there's no such command, you get an error.

If you want to test if there's anything in `$TEST_CRITERIA`, you need to use the `test` command, also available as `[`.

```
if [ -n "$TEST_CRITERIA" ]
```

Note that since you didn't quote `$(useless "Hello World")` each word that it outputs becomes a separate argument to `call-and-report`.

If you want the value of `$TEST_CRITERIA` printed on the terminal, you need to do that explicitly in `call-and-report`.

```
function useless
{
    echo "$1"
    return 0
}

function call-and-report
{
    TEST_CRITERIA="$1"
    echo "$TEST_CRITERIA"

    if [ -n "$TEST_CRITERIA" ]
    then
        echo "passed"
    else
        echo "failed"
    fi
}

call-and-report "$(useless  "Hello World")"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `$(useless  "Hello World")` will return

```
Hello World
```

So you are calling your `call-and-report` function with 2 arguments:

```
call-and-report Hello World
```

And in that function, you take the first one, `Hello` into your variable.

Then you do `if Hello`, which generates the error because indeed, `Hello` is not a command, so it neither succeeds nor fails.